# Can we use the native font instead of Arial for Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, design, fonts

First of all, I'm a bit allergic to default fonts like Arial, Times New Roman etc.

You already are aware that, all the Stack Exchange sites (except a few) recently switched to the default fonts:

```
font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

That's not bad and works everywhere - that's the real cause - I appreciate that.

But the good thing is: recently Github and WordPress switched to the Native Font Family that's nicer *to me*.

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Github    | font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| WordPress | font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I think it's a community decision that's not that bad to follow.

It may look like I'm proposing something that interests *me* only — but actually I'm asking for something nicer, soothing and not buggy. I hope I'm clear with my POV.

Can we go with such a native font family?

Comment: Will this maybe be more likely to cause all kind of rendering bugs across platforms?

Comment: Is your question *should* we have it or *can* we have it? The first is a [tag:discussion], the other a [tag:feature-request]. You might to change your wording or the tag.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I's unsure how to tag it, so I added `discussion` instead of `feature-request`, because I thought it'd be the community decision whether to take it as a feature request or leave it. I'm proposing something smart _to me_, and I hope would be for the community.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this yourself, just add a custom stylesheet (how this works varies per browser) with the following rule:

```
body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol" !important;
}
```

Comment: I think the discussion is more interesting than fixing this for a single user.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's more like a workaround if this [feature-request] gets [status-declined].

Comment: It is a discussion.

Comment: I'd argue that it's both.

Comment: @Glorfindel is it a kind of joke, I'm afraid!!